# displaying UILabel text using code

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to display the float value in label using code

i tried with the following code but it doesn't work!!!! can you please help me out.

find my code for your reference:

```
 UILabel * label;
    float a;
    a=2;
     { label = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A:%d", a]];}
```

but it is giving a error as `:SIGABRT`

Comment: Inside which class is that code? I mean, what is **self** in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should create label, then set formatted text to `text` property, and after this show on your view (self.view assumes you use it into UIViewController)

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", a]];
[self.view addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A:%f", a]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this
  UILabel * label;

```
float a;

label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",a];
```